# Partial arrow classifier as an (adjunction-related) universal arrow

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Goldblatt gives a brief overview of adjunctions in his "Topoi", and one of the exercises asks to characterise the partial arrow classifier in terms of some universal arrow.

Well, I gave it some thought, and I'm not even sure where to go from there. The main problem I have is that in the "there exists" part I have only one arrow (the PAC itself), and in the "such that for every" part I'm given two arrows (the "top-left" components of the PAC pullback), and I'm just not sure how to construct a category and a functor into/from it that'd allow for both. I tried something along the lines of the diagonalization functor used for (co)products derivation via adjoints, but it didn't get me far (or anywhere, frankly).

So, how would I do that?

Again, my exposition to adjoints is limited to several pages of "Topoi", so I likely miss some otherwise well-known results.

Comment: it might help to give a little more background. As it stands now, I find your explanation of your attempt somewhat cryptic.

Comment: Well, to have an adjunction you need to have two categories. One is the category the partial object classifiers live in, of course. What is the other? You should think about that first.

Comment: To clarify the question: If the question were instead about subobject classifiers, would the answer look something like "the (right) universal object $\Omega$ with a given subobject $\Omega_0$"?